# Облачное хранилище с неограниченным трафиком

Tags: файлы, хранилище, облачное-хранилище

**Здравствуйте.**

Знаете ли вы какой-нибудь сервис облачного хранения данных, типа DropBox, но только с неограниченным трафиком? DropBox сильно ограничивает пропускную способность канала , и, если ссылки собирают много трафика, то DropBox просто-напросто ставит бан на аккаунт. При каждой последующей попытке доступа к определенному файлу через ссылку DropBox будет выдавать 509-ую ошибку( BandWidth Error ). Поэтому, хотелось бы найти похожий сервис, но с неограниченным трафиком. Желательно с прямыми ссылками и желательно без файловых помоек.

---

P.S  Если такое вообще существует, за бесплатно. =)

Comment: `Яндекс.Диск` / `Google.Drive`?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, там, опять же ограничена пропускная способность( в Google Drive точно, насчет Яндекса не уверен, проверю ). Плюс, там не прилагаются "прямые" ссылки к файлам.

Comment: @Asen Ну, вообще говоря, бесплатный сервис с неограниченным каналом и прямыми ссылками - это звучит уж слишком фантастично. Если откинуть пожелание бесплатности, то это легко решается арендой `VDS'а` за пару десятков `$` в месяц.

Comment: Okay, так иного выхода нет? Получается, что то, что мне необходимо, всегда не бесплатно? Если так, то придется взаимодействовать с дибильными системами оплаты...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если вам просто "тупо" нужно где-то хранить файлы с открытым для каждого доступом( за бесплатно ), то почему бы не завести какой-нибудь бесплатный хостинг с FTP. Таких ныне полно и появляются с каждым месяцем все лучшие, предлагающие большой спектр разнообразных услуг **за бесплатно**! Так, что я предлагаю вам выбрать не "облако", а FTP.

Comment: Идея неплохая =)

Answer (score 4):

- [**`S3.Amazon.com`**](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing) - Дорого и много...

Comment: Не совсем то...облом платить. Не денег жалко, а именно лень. Там сложная система оплаты...

Comment: @Asen, Дааа, сложная: подключил кредитку и `оно` по тихому с неё деньги тянет XD

Comment: Там дорогой именно трафик, само хранение достаточно дешево обходится. К примеру за 50 GB в год уйдет примерно `0.093*50*12` = $55.8, для сравнения годовая подписка в dropbox стоит $100 за 50 GB

Comment: Есть ещё сервис [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn), который даже в бесплатном плане предлагает свою CDN. Если разобраться и настроить выдачу так, чтобы не брался файл каждый раз с того же S3, а выдавался из кэша их CDN, то впишетесь в бесплатную квоту S3 трафика.

Answer (score 0):

Может это подойдет [cubby](https://www.cubby.com/)?

Comment: Нет, это,к сожалению, не подойдет, так как данный сервис является, скорее, аналогом дропбоксу...а значит, пропускная способность канала там вряд ли больше, если не меньше...все равно спасибо =)

Comment: А не проще ли, купить хороший хостинг и работать с ним по ftp?

Answer (score 0):

Может DiskaNet.ru? безлимитный траффик и доступ по ftp

Comment: Если бы я не знал, что автор вопроса имеет дюжину аккаунтов, то я бы тут написал, что он уже дважды забанен, и ему уже не интересен ответ на этот вопрос.  
А вообще это интересная практика - отвечать на старые, как радикулит мамонта, вопросы.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, я тут ЖИВОЙ и ЧИТАЮ это =)